# Using text from a cell in a formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to use the text from a cell in a formula in Google Sheets.

I have a document with multiple sheets that a variety of people can edit with a H,M,L (high, medium, low) value from a drop-down list. Each person has their own tab in the Google Sheet.

I then have a dashboard that populates based on their choices of H,M,L. I know that I can use the formula **=('Jay Delacruz'!C6)** for example to populate a cell in another sheet by manually selecting the cells on the other sheet.

However, I am looking to make quite a few of these documents automatically with another Google Script that I am running that creates the individual sheets from a roster of names on the first tab.

My question is, is it possible to have a **=('Jay Delacruz'!C6)** type formula that instead of the sheet reference it can pull the name of the person from the roster, as this will match exactly the sheets that are automatically generated by the script I have running.

So I would essentially have a pre-populated dashboard of formulae that would become valid once the sheets are created with the names, as created by the other script.

If it makes it a little clearer, there is a link below to make a copy of the Sheet I am working with. All names were randomly generated, so don't reference any real people or data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NiXqko8SibD6VsfrnFcj7e7c99Hg-RoSlHVAYWb0E94/copy

Thank you in advance!
Liam

Comment: Try =INDIRECT(C1&"!C6")

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you. Do you know if there is any way to replicate that formula down without manually changing the "!C6" part?

Comment: Down? or to the right? If the latter, just select the cell and drag to the right using the fill handle. The "!C6" part will not change because it's a string.

Comment: Thank you for that. I can replicate to the right no problem and have manually changed the string so that all is displayed correctly.

However, when I run the script that creates the sheets from the roster I get a #REF with the following message on each cell:
Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'BLOGGS Joe!C8'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.
When I manually re-enter the formula it works, but over hundreds of cells that is not ideal - is there a workaround for this? Many thanks

Comment: Since you are already using script, maybe write the formulas to the range through script ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=INDIRECT(C1&"!C6")
```

Also see [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) for more info on INDIRECT() function.